# cookie php как задать время жизни

Tags: php, cookie

помогите с cookie php а именно нужно задать время жизни для куки 30 дней

```
setcookie("some_cookie_name", serialize($get_cook), '');
```

как задать в миллисекундах это будет или как вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Время жизни для куки 30 дней:

```
setcookie('some_cookie_name', serialize($get_cook), time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
```

Answer (score 2):

Время жизни для куки 30 дней с помощью [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
setcookie('some_cookie_name', serialize($get_cook), strtotime("+30 day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`setcookie("some_cookie_name", serialize($get_cook), time() + 2592000);`

где time текущее время а 2592000 - 30 дней в секундах. (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)